# How can I provide that python-bridge sees my python packages in node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, electron, python-venv

I try to create desktop application with **Electron.js** and I need use some **python packages** in this application. I use **python-bridge** to run python codes in **node.js**. Now I can run python codes in node.js. But I need to add some python packages in it.

First, I created a python environment and installed some packages in it. I activated virtual environment then ran 'npm start' in it. This worked.

But I think this is not good idea for a desktop application. Because I won't be able to use this method when the app is released.

Also we have another way. When I read the docs about [python-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-bridge), I saw this solution. But I can't use it. It doesn't see my python packages yet.

```
var python = pythonBridge({
    env: {PYTHONPATH: '/foo/bar'}
});
```

This is js code in my **main.js** file to set python-bridge

```
const pythonBridge = require('python-bridge')

let python = pythonBridge({
    // python: 'python3',
    env: {
        PYTHONPATH: 'venv'
    }
});
```

and continues with these lines

```
python.ex`import pandas as pd`

python.ex`
def read_data():
    return pd.read_excel('data.xlsx').to_json()
`
python`read_data()`.then(df => console.log(df))
python.end();
```

This error occurs when I run `npm start`

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hasan.ismayilov\projects\other\ElectronJS\firstTry\node_modules\python-bridge\node_python_bridge.py", line 101, in <module>
    _exec(_compile(data['code'], '<input>', 'exec'), _locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Unhandled rejection Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hasan.ismayilov\projects\other\ElectronJS\firstTry\node_modules\python-bridge\node_python_bridge.py", line 104, in <module>
    value = eval(_compile(data['code'], '<input>', 'eval'), _locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in read_data
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

    at ChildProcess.onMessage (C:\Users\hasan.ismayilov\projects\other\ElectronJS\firstTry\node_modules\python-bridge\index.js:44:32)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:939:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

Venv and main.js are in same directory

[image]